# Erro ao executar query dentro de função

Tags: php, mysqli

estou tendo problemas para fazer uma busca no banco mysql dentro de uma função em PHP, se eu faço a busca fora da função funciona normalmente mas eu gostaria que fosse feita dentro da função para mim chamar quando quiser.

Erro: `Undefined variable: conn in path\functions.php on line 4`

e
`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in path\functions.php on line 4`

Meu esquema.

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'banco');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf('Connect failed: ', mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $conn->select_db('banco');
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
    function get_datas(){
        $datas = array();
        if($result = $conn->query("SELECT valor1, valor2, valor3 FROM tabela")){
            while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                $datas[] = array(
                    'chave1' => $row[0],
                    'chave2' => $row[1],
                    'chave3' => $row[2]
                );
            }
            return $datas;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
  include_once "db_connection.php";
  include_once "functions.php";
  $results = get_datas();
    if(count($results) == 0){
        echo 'Desculpe, mais não foram encontrados dados';
    }
    else{
        foreach($results as $data){
            echo $data['valor1'].'<br>';
            echo $data['valor2'].'<br>';
            echo $data['valor3'].'<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Problema é que a variavel `$conn` dentro da sua função não foi definida, que deveria ser a conexão com o banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução para seu problema é criar uma função com a conexão e chamar ela dentro da(s) outra(s) função(ões):

```
function conn(){
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'banco');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf('Connect failed: ', mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $conn->select_db('banco');
    return $conn;
}

function get_datas(){
    $datas = array();
    $conn = conn();
    if($result = $conn->query("SELECT valor1, valor2, valor3 FROM tabela")){
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
            $datas[] = array(
                'chave1' => $row[0],
                'chave2' => $row[1],
                'chave3' => $row[2]
            );
        }
        return $datas;
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Mas de uma pesquisada em `classes` e `métodos construtores`, ter uma classe que faça todo trabalho de conexão, CRUD, adianta bem o serviço, pelo menos ao meu ver.